# How to add rounded borders to a container using the border property?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a container and need to add border rounding on multiple sides. I've tried using `borderRadius` but I'm getting an error because I'm using the `border`. Tell me by what method can I add rounding for the container not from all sides, but only from some?

```
return Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: index == 0
              ? const Border(
                  bottom:
                      BorderSide(width: 2, color: constants.Colors.purpleMain),
                )
              : const Border(
                  bottom:
                      BorderSide(width: 2, color: constants.Colors.purpleMain),
                ),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use param `borderRadius` in `BoxDecoration`. Parameters of `BorderRadius.only` are `topLeft`, `topRight`, `bottomLeft`, `bottomRight`.

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(4.0), // only top right
        ),
    ),
    ...
)
```